# Could use help formatting data correctly for a Keras SimpleRNN

Tags: python, keras, classification, recurrent-neural-network, word-embedding

I'm struggling a bit getting data into the right format for a simpleRNN, or I'm struggling to define the model correctly. I'm hoping someone can spot the problem?

I'm trying to do classification of a list `X` of vectors of length 278 that contain integer values chosen from a dictionary `vocab` of length 9026 features as either belonging to class 0 or 1. Here's an example of my input data:

```
X=[[1,822,773,54,51,...],[2,3,1,41,3,...],[121,17,311,4,12,...],...]
y=[0,1,1,...]
```

So for example `np.array(X).shape=(1000,278)` and `len(y)=1000`
My model is:

```
model.add(L.InputLayer([None],dtype='int32'))
model.add(L.Embedding(input_dim=len(vocab)+1,\
                      output_dim=64,\
                      input_length=278))
model.add(L.SimpleRNN(64,return_sequences=True))
model.add(L.TimeDistributed(L.Dense(1,activation='softmax')))
model.compile(optimizer='adam',\
              loss='categorical_crossentropy',\
              metrics=['accuracy']
             )
print(model.summary())

_________________________________________________________________
Layer (type)                 Output Shape              Param #   
=================================================================
embedding_8 (Embedding)      (None, 278, 64)           577728    
_________________________________________________________________
simple_rnn_7 (SimpleRNN)     (None, 278, 64)           8256      
_________________________________________________________________
time_distributed_7 (TimeDist (None, 278, 1)            65        
=================================================================
Total params: 586,049
Trainable params: 586,049
Non-trainable params: 0
_________________________________________________________________
None
```

I prepare them as follows:

```
X=np.array(X)
y=keras.utils.to_categorical(y)

frac=0.3
random_state=42
X_train,X_tmp,y_train,y_tmp = \
    train_test_split(X,y,test_size=frac,random_state=random_state,\
                         stratify=y)
train=(X_train,y_train)
test=(X_tmp,y_tmp)
```

When I run the model:

```
model.fit(train[0],train[1],verbose=0,\
              batch_size=batch_size,\
              epochs=epochs,validation_data=test)
```

I get the following error:

```
ValueError: Error when checking target: expected time_distributed_1 
to have 3 dimensions, but got array with shape (5450, 2)
```

If I change the input data to

```
train=(X_train,y_train[:,:,np.newaxis])
test=(X_tmp,y_tmp[:,:,np.newaxis])
```

and run the model, I get this error:

```
ValueError: Error when checking target: expected time_distributed_1 
to have shape (278, 2) but got array with shape (2, 1)
```

OK so obviously I've got something wrong since my final dense layer is looking for shape 278 and not 2. So I tried this model without explicitly defining the input_length:

```
model.add(L.InputLayer([None],dtype='int32'))
model.add(L.Embedding(input_dim=len(vocab)+1,\
                      output_dim=64))
model.add(L.SimpleRNN(64,return_sequences=True))
model.add(L.TimeDistributed(L.Dense(1,activation='softmax')))
model.compile(optimizer='adam',\
              loss='categorical_crossentropy',\
              metrics=['accuracy']
             )
print(model.summary())

_________________________________________________________________
Layer (type)                 Output Shape              Param #   
=================================================================
embedding_10 (Embedding)     (None, None, 64)          577728    
_________________________________________________________________
simple_rnn_9 (SimpleRNN)     (None, None, 64)          8256      
_________________________________________________________________
time_distributed_9 (TimeDist (None, None, 2)           130       
=================================================================
Total params: 586,114
Trainable params: 586,114
Non-trainable params: 0
```

and when I run the model, I get

```
ValueError: Error when checking target: expected time_distributed_9
to have shape (None, 2) but got array with shape (2, 1)
```

I'm very confused. Can anyone help me diagnose this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why are you using `TimeDistributed`? You don't need that at all. For each vector of length 278 you want to predict one and only one number which is between 0 and 1. Therefore the output shape of last layer should be `(None,1)`. Remove the `return_sequences` argument of `SimpleRNN` layer as well.You don't need that as well. Like this:

```
model.add(L.SimpleRNN(64))
model.add(L.Dense(1,activation='sigmoid'))
```

Further, you should use `'sigmoid'` as the activation function to make the last layer outputs a value between 0 and 1. And change the `'categorical_crossentropy'` to `'binary_crossentropy'`. You also don't need to convert the `y` to categorical. It is already zeros and ones and that's fine (just convert it to a numpy array); remember, you are doing binary classification here.

Plus, use the first model. Your second model does not make sense since you mentioned all of the input vectors are the same length (i.e. 278).

And one final point: remove that `InputLayer`. It is redundant. You are already setting the input shape in your embedding layer.

Comment: I thought that `TimeDistributed` is needed because by itself, `Dense` applies one dense layer over all time steps at once, while `TimeDistributed` applies a dense layer to each time step individually.

Comment: @AstroBen Why do you need to consider each timestep individually? You want to find a mapping from 278 timesteps to only one single value, right? So you must have good reasons for considering each of those timesteps individually. Have you first tried training the model without using TimeDistributed and see if your accuracy is low?

Comment: @AstroBen As you can see, the output shape of last Dense layer is `(None, 278, 1)`. This means for each sample (i.e. vector of length 278) you are predicting an array of shape `(278,1)` which is 278 values?!!! You don't want 278 values, you want one single value (i.e. between zero and one).

Comment: @AstroBen In other words, you don't want to classify each single timestep. Rather, you want to classify 278 timesteps (i.e. a time-series).

Comment: @AstroBen Please make a concrete example. Let's say you have a sentence: "This is a good day and I am a happy human". So the input of the model is this sentence (or its index based representation). Now what do you want to predict (i.e. output) or learn (i.e. unsupervised learning maybe) based on this input?

Comment: sorry I was confusing TimeDistributed with Bidirectional. Like I said, stupid error....